# Persistent URL for GitHub repo subfolder

Tags: github

I would like to provide a URL to a subfolder of a GitHub repo in a paper I am about to submit. I thought the link should look like `github.com/account/reponame/folder/subfolder`, but I realised now that when navigating through the repo, I need to write `github.com/account/reponame/tree/main/folder/subfolder` for the link to work. Can I assume a link with this format to be persistent, or is there a better way of ensuring that the URL is useful for a long time?

Answer (score 1):

the /tree/master/ just indicates the master branch is being accessed. The link would be active till someone with edit access to the repo changes the folder structure or deletes it. If it is a repo with shared edit access, I would suggest you to fork it and make it private and then share the link from the fork so that no one would make changes to the path other than you.

Comment: So if I were to create a branch which I then do not push to anymore, I could link to that instead, and it would persist as long as nobody removes the repo or that branch?

Comment: You could use the branch protection rules option in the git repo settings under branches  to Define branch protection rules to disable force pushing, prevent branches from being deleted, and optionally require status checks before merging

Answer (score 1):

It is safer to refer to a specific commit, that is:

```
github.com/account/reponame/tree/COMMITID/main/folder/subfolder
```

Where `COMMITID` is the SHA hash of your commit, which should look like `56e05fced214c44a37759efa2dfc25a65d8ae98d`

That way, you can still push changes to your repo, and the reviewers still will get access to the specific version you want.